# Wordpress/PHP: Show different landing pages under conditions

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I built a Wordpress website for employees of a company. The website can be fully accessed by everyone. However, I would like to show a different landing page for internal and external visitors.

I can check whether someone accesses through the company's network by checking the availability of the intranet page "www.intranet.examplecompany.com".

Here is my first idea, that did not work:

```php
function url_check($url) { 
    $hdrs = @get_headers($url); 
    return is_array($hdrs) ? preg_match('/^HTTP\\/\\d+\\.\\d+\\s+2\\d\\d\\s+.*$/',$hdrs[0]) : false; 
}

//check URL
if(url_check('http://www.intranet.examplecompany.com')){
    //URL valid
    //show different landing page
    header('Location: http://myWebsite.com/differentLandingPage');

} else {
    //URL not valid
    //show regular homepage
    header('Location: http://myWebsite.com/Homepage1');
}
```

And another question: where exactly do I paste my code? I tried to add it in front of index.php which did not work.
The code should only be executed when you ask for "http://myWebsite.com/". Not for any subpages. Maybe there is completely different approach by JavaScript or plugins?

Comment: function url_check($url) { 
is missing on top

Comment: why aren't you doing this on the webserver level? using virtual hosts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, place the code for checking the URL to your `functions.php` file. That file should be your first choice for holding all of your theme customizations.

There are two approaches for checking the URL and executing the redirect.

#### Template files

Since you only want to execute the code if users visit your home page, you can look into [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). When your users visit any page on your website, Wordpress needs to determine which template to use for rendering the output. The templates used for the home page are any of `front-page.php`, `home.php`, `page.php` or `index.php`.

If you check the URL inside `front-page.php` or `home.php`, then you can be sure that the code will execute only if users visit your website's home page.

#### Wordpress actions

Wordpress action hooks allow you to register a function that should run before or after a standard Wordpress action. For example, if you want to do something after Wordpress has been initialized and before any output is generated, you can create a hook for action `init`. See the [Wordpress reference page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for an exhaustive list of all available actions.

An example of what you might want to do:

```
function check_url() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        // You probably only want to check the non-admin pages
        return;
    }

    if(url_check('someWebsite')){
        // Do what you need here
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'check_url' );
```

You might also consider using the redirect function from Wordpress: [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/).